# SQL query to display each horse that has been added in the same event as its father(sire)

Tags: sql, ms-access

These are the following tables I have created:

```
CREATE TABLE Horse
(horse_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
 horse_name CHAR(30),
 horse_colour CHAR(30)
 horse_sire INTEGER,
 horse_dam INTEGER,
 horse_born INTEGER.
 horse_died INTEGER,
 horse_gender CHAR(2)
);

CREATE TABLE Event
(event_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
 event_name CHAR(30)
);

CREATE TABLE Entry
(event_id INTEGER,
 horse_id INTEGER
);
```

Then I inserted the values for these 3 tables:

```
INSERT INTO Horse (horse_id,horse_name,horse_colour,horse_sire,horse_dam,horse_born,horse_gender)
VALUES (101,'Flash','white',201,301,1990,'S');
INSERT INTO Horse (horse_id,horse_name,horse_colour,horse_sire,horse_dam,horse_born,horse_gender)
VALUES (102,'Star','brown',201,302,1991,'M');
INSERT INTO Horse (horse_id,horse_name,horse_colour,horse_sire,horse_dam,horse_born,horse_gender)
VALUES (201,'Boxer','grey',401,501,1980,'S');
INSERT INTO Horse (horse_id,horse_name,horse_colour,horse_sire,horse_dam,horse_born,horse_gender)
VALUES (301,'Daisy','white',401,502,1981,'M');
INSERT INTO Horse (horse_id,horse_name,horse_colour,horse_sire,horse_dam,horse_born,horse_died,horse_gender)
VALUES (302,'Tinkle','brown',401,501,1981,1994,'M');
INSERT INTO Horse (horse_id,horse_name,horse_colour,horse_dam,horse_born,horse_died,horse_gender)
VALUES (401,'Snowy','white',301,1976,1984,'S');
INSERT INTO Horse (horse_id,horse_name,horse_colour,horse_dam,horse_born,horse_died,horse_gender)
VALUES (501,'Bluebell','grey',301,1975,1982,'M');
INSERT INTO Horse (horse_id,horse_name,horse_colour,horse_dam,horse_born,horse_died,horse_gender)
VALUES (502,'Sally','white',301,1974,1987,'M');

INSERT INTO Event (event_id,event_name)
VALUES (101,'Dressage');
INSERT INTO Event (event_id,event_name)
VALUES (102,'Jumping');
INSERT INTO Event (event_id,event_name)
VALUES (103,'Jumping');
INSERT INTO Event (event_id,event_name)
VALUES (201,'Led in');
INSERT INTO Event (event_id,event_name)
VALUES (301,'Led in');
INSERT INTO Event (event_id,event_name)
VALUES (401,'Dressage');
INSERT INTO Event (event_id,event_name)
VALUES (501,'Dressage');
INSERT INTO Event (event_id,event_name)
VALUES (502,'Flag and Pole');

INSERT INTO Entry (event_id,horse_id)
VALUES (101,101);
INSERT INTO Entry (event_id,horse_id)
VALUES (101,102);
INSERT INTO Entry (event_id,horse_id)
VALUES (101,201);
INSERT INTO Entry (event_id,horse_id)
VALUES (101,301);
INSERT INTO Entry (event_id,horse_id)
VALUES (102,201);
INSERT INTO Entry (event_id,horse_id)
VALUES (103,102);
INSERT INTO Entry (event_id,horse_id)
VALUES (201,101);
INSERT INTO Entry (event_id,horse_id)
VALUES (301,301);
INSERT INTO Entry (event_id,horse_id)
VALUES (401,102);
INSERT INTO Entry (event_id,horse_id)
VALUES (501,102);
INSERT INTO Entry (event_id,horse_id)
VALUES (501,301);
```

This is the following question:

**For each horse that has been entered in the same event as its sire (father), list the
names of the two horses and of the event.**

**The output of this query should be as shown below:**

```
Horse  Sire  Event

Flash  Boxer Dressage
Star   Boxer Dressage
```

This is what I have tried:

```
SELECT TOP 2 H1.horse_name AS Horse, H2.horse_name AS Sire, event_name AS Event
FROM Horse AS H1, Horse AS H2, Event, Entry
WHERE H1.horse_sire = H2.horse_id
AND H1.horse_sire = Entry.horse_id
AND H2.horse_id = Entry.horse_id
AND Event.event_id = Entry.event_id
AND (H1.horse_sire IS NOT NULL AND H1.horse_dam is NOT NULL );
```

And this is the output I am getting after executing the query:

```
Horse  Sire  Event

Flash  Boxer Dressage
Flash  Boxer Jumping
```

I almost got the desired output based on what the question wanted but the only problem is that I am getting 'Flash' instead of 'Star' in the first column (Horse) of the 2nd row.

In other words, my code just needs a small fix.
It would be really helpful if my code can be corrected and re-written.

So where is the mistake am I making?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a separate join to Entry for the sire because its entry is not the same as its offspring's entry.

```
SELECT H1.horse_name AS Horse, H2.horse_name AS Sire, event_name AS Event
FROM Horse AS H1, Horse AS H2, Event, Entry, Entry As SireEntry
WHERE H1.horse_sire = H2.horse_id
AND H1.horse_id = Entry.horse_id
AND H2.horse_id = SireEntry.horse_id
AND Event.event_id = Entry.event_id
AND Event.event_id = SireEntry.event_id;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/16c06/2